# To prove a Cauchy sequence is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

If $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy and has a convergent subsequence with limit $x$, show that $\{x_n\}$ is convergent with limit $x$.

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: Definitions are your friends.  Use what is given to prove that the definition of converging to $x$ is satisfied.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add the upvote.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to help you unravel some of the definitions and give a hint.

Let $\epsilon >0$.

Suppose $\{x_{n}\}$ has a subsequence $\{x_{n_{k}}\}$ that converges to $x$. Then, there is an $N_{1}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n_{k}\geq k\geq N_{1}$ implies $|x_{n_{k}}-x|<\epsilon/2$.

Since $\{x_{n}\}$ is Cauchy, there is an $N_{2}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n,m\geq N_{2}$ imply $|x_{n}-x_{m}|<\epsilon/2$.

Let $N=\max\{N_{1},N_{2}\}$. Can you think how you might use the triangle inequality to conclude that $|x_{n}-x|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$?

Comment: yes i know how to use triangle inequality.thanks

Comment: Does $k$ have to be greater than or equal to $N$ in the inequality $|x_n-x|\leq |x_n-x_{n_k}|+|x_{n_k}-x|\le \frac {\epsilon} 2+\frac {\epsilon} 2$?

Comment: I have modified my answer to require that $n_{k}\geq N_{1}\implies |x_{n_{k}}-x|<\epsilon/2$.

Comment: So $n_k\geq N\implies k\geq N$, right?

Comment: Not quite. It's possible that $n_{5}\geq N$ but that $5<N$. The important thing is that $k\geq N\implies n_{k}\geq N$.

Comment: Please make it clear what value of $k$ you are using. I know that the proof doesn't need to, but I am trying to understand why it works. Must $n_k\ge k\ge n$? I can't figure it out.

Comment: I think you're just confused about all of the different variables. Let me write it this way: suppose $k\geq N$. Then, $n_{k}\geq k\geq N$. Hence, $|x_{n_{k}}-x|<\epsilon/2$ and $|x_{k}-x_{n_{k}}|<\epsilon/2$. Using the triangle inequality, we conclude that $|x_{k}-x|<\epsilon$ for all $k\geq N$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39964/discussion-between-ahorn-and-ervx).

Answer (score 1):

Let {$x_n$} be cauchy sequence in metric space $X$ with metric $d$.

By Assumption, $x_n$ has convergent subsequence $x_{n_k}$ such that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}x_{n_k}=a$ for some $a\in X$.

Let $\epsilon>0$. There exists $K\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $k\geq K$, then $d(x_{n_k},a)<\epsilon$.

Since $x_n$ is cauchy, there exists $M\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n,m\geq M$, then $d(x_n,x_m)<\epsilon$.

Let $N=max\{M,K\}$.

Then If $n\geq N$, then $d(x_n,a)\leq d(x_n,x_{n_N})+d(x_{n_M},a)<2\epsilon$