# What values are used for the counter $k$ in this proof involving a convergent subsequence?

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces

> **Lemma** Suppose that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in a metric space $(X,d)$, and $x\in X$. Also suppose $(x_{n_k})$ is a subsequence of $(x_n)$ such that $x_{n_k}\to x$ as $k\to \infty$. Then $x_n\to x$ as $n\to \infty$.
>
> **Proof** Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Choose $N_1\in \mathbb N^+$ such that $k\ge N_1$ implies that $d(x_{n_k},x)<\frac {\epsilon} 2$. Choose $N_2\in\mathbb N^+$ such that $m\ge n\ge N_2$ implies that $d(x_m,x_n)<\frac{\epsilon} 2$. Let $N$ be the maximum of $N_1$ and $N_2$. Now $d(x_n,x)\le d(x_n,x_{n_k})+d(x_{n_k},x)$ for all $k$. Using this, we get that $n\ge N$ implies that $d(x_n,x)<\epsilon$. $\small\blacksquare$

What condition must $k$ satisfy for the above proof to hold?

My thought is that $n_k$ must be large enough such that $n_k\ge n$ for all $k>N_k$, some $N_k\in \mathbb N$.

[Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1790370/151595)

Comment: All that is required is that $\langle n_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a strictly increasing sequence of indices, so that $\langle x_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ really is a subsequence of $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

What $k$ needs to satisfy is $k\geq N_1$. Since $N_1 \leq max\{N_1,N_2\}$ this implies that $k$ maintains the condition needed or else the first statement would not be true since there is a number greater than $N_1$ in which the assertion claimed is false.